# jQuery UI - Sort table rows and allow dropping ON a table row at the same time?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, tablerow

I'm working on a task management application. Each task is presented in a seperate table row. I want the user to be able to sort the table rows, as well as drop a row into another one which will nest the tasks.

So far, i've figured out how to sort the elements. No biggie. The problem is i need to be able to drop the table rows on other table rows as well, and that seems to be a bit trickier. I understand i need to use `draggable` and `droppable` in combination with `sortable`? Or maybe i don't need `sortable` at all, i don't know.

I tried implementing `draggable` but nothing seems to happen. [Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/bRbSn/2/).

Can anyone point me in the right direction or give me some advice?

**Edit:** When you drop the row on another row, i don't actually want to nest the rows, but rather hide the dragged row. After it's dropped i'll make an ajax call setting the "catcher row" as a parent in the database.

Comment: Nesting table rows is tricky. Intermediate `<table>` elements would have to be created and inserted. Any chance you can use `<div>` elements instead?

Comment: Oh, i should have been more clear. I don't want it to show up as nested, i just want to hide the parent element when it was dropped on top of another row. Then it'll make an ajax call under the hood setting the "container row" (the row that catched the row) as parent. Do you understand? I'll update the question.

Comment: You could try using this plugin: http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/

Comment: Yup, i googled as well! Without actually reading, it seems like it only allows for sorting table rows, right? It doesn't actually allow for nesting, does it?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to combine both draggable and droppable with sortable, check this [JQFAQ.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-use-jquery-sortable-and-droppable-in-single-table/) topic, here they enable droppable and sortable in list.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/bRbSn/30/. I can now drop rows on top of other rows, but i can no longer re-order them correctly. If i try to re-order a row between two rows (in the gap), it will assume i'm hovering over one of the rows and remove it when i drop, instead of re-ordering it. Try it out. Any ideas? Thanks by the way!

Comment: I just edited above post and changed JQFAQ.com link pls check that, i think that's what you looking for.

Comment: The problem still persists. The problem now is i can't re-order rows without dragging it to the absolute top/bottom of the list. If i want to put a row in the middle, it doesn't understand and automatically makes it a child instead of re-ordering it. Do you see my problem?

Comment: While dragging at some position you can able to drop it between two rows.

Comment: I can't seem to get that to work. Tried latest FF and Chrome on Windows. Chrome also doesn't get the "gap" between rows when you try to re-order them, it only shows up in Firefox.